# Replacing `reduce` terminal method with `forEach` in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have made a method to build a wall. Im using stream approach, at first I used `reduce` but Im trying to see if `forEach` works.

the following is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Need three integer arguments: width height #bricks");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int width = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int height = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int numberOfBricks = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        assert numberOfBricks <= width * height: "Too many bricks";
        System.out.printf("Will build a wall %d wide and %d tall%n", 
            width, height);
        System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(width,"==")));
        final Wall wall = new Wall(width, height); //UPDATE
        Wall trumpWall = 
            Stream.generate(() -> new Ball(10.0))
             .filter(b -> b.colour == Ball.Colour.RED)
             .map(Brick::new)
             .limit(numberOfBricks)
             .forEach(wall::lay) //UPDATE
                Wall::linkTwoWalls);
        System.out.println(trumpWall);
    }    
}
```

can anyone suggest how to fix this problem? I found using forEach is more simpler and therefore easier to read.

Comment: Why would you think `forEach()` can work, given that it doesn't have a return value, ergo it cannot return a Wall?

Comment: its returning a wall, why wouldnt it work? or maybe I have to change the code?

Comment: Why do you think `forEach()` takes 3 parameters, when it obviously only takes 1? Look at the javadoc of [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-): `void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`. **One** parameter. **No** return value.

Comment: What’s the rationale behind replacing a working method invocation with an invocation of an entirely different incompatible method? “I have made a method to move. … at first I used a `car` but I’m trying to see if a `rock` works. … can anyone suggest how to fix this problem?”

Comment: because im learning java. And one of my mentor said, try changing `reduce` to `forEach` he said, the method that ive done with reduce is the "easy" way, but with futher programming complexcity it can be messy. so he said, try using forEach instead @Holger

Comment: If the mentor said that, you should stop listening to him. Using `forEach` is the habit of people mentally stuck with loops. With streams, the actual challenge is to get over it and find the right tool for the job. If you found a solution using `reduce` and it even looks easy (or perhaps *natural*), you’ve done everything right. Replacing that with `forEach` makes no sense. It makes even solving your current task messy, not to speak of “further programming complexity”…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forEach` method only takes a `Consumer<T>`. You can only *do stuff* with the elements, not returning a value.

What you are trying to do here is just to call `lay(brick)` for each brick, right?

Then maybe you can create the `Wall` object outside the stream method chain first:

```
final Wall wall = new Wall(width, height);
```

Then in `forEach`, do this:

```
.forEach(wall::lay);
```

After that line is executed, `wall` will become a wall with a lot of bricks.

Apparently, you also want to link two walls together. Unfortunately, I failed to understand which two walls you are trying to link. If you explained a bit more, I can help you.

Comment: the `LinkTwoWalls` is to "append" the wall we made to the wall that is already been build (if theres any).

Comment: @Kutam why do you want to connect them? Aren't you building one single wall? Also, can you show the wall class code?

Comment: because we are defining a new wall. with the set of attributes and parameters such as the widht, height, amount of bricks, etc. I also added the wall class in the question

Comment: actually, I tried compiling it again with your suggestion. Its working. Can you explain to me why is this the case?

Comment: @Kutam I think I know what's happening here. You were using the `reduce` method. If you do that, you need to use a bifunction (the part where you link two walls) because each iteration, a brand new wall is created. You have to link these newly created walls together at the end of  each iteration. But if you use foreach, you don't need it because you are just adding bricks to a single wall.

Comment: im thinking of using collect. can you help me? I think i need to define accept() and combine() method in the wall class. any ideas?

Comment: Well, that's another question. I suggest you do some research first, try to do it on your own, and if you are really stuck, post another question! @Kutam

Comment: Okay sure, can you guide me tho? So is this correct, im going to implement an accept() and combine method() in the `wall` class. Do I need to change the implementation in the `DonaldTrump` class?

Comment: so maybe supplier is the Wall, for the accept() it will accept the width and height. for the combine() method, it is to combine from the "accept" method to the final method in `DonaldTrump` class? am I correct?